# Force sending event for sessions without a logged in user

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, logging, session

Is there any possibility using the Google Analytics API to check if the session is logged in or not? I have a problem with destination page (it is not set), and I want to resend the event when the session is not logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using the Google Analytics API to check if the session is logged or not". Are you referring to modifying the tracking script to handle exceptions? Please elaborate on the issue and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

1) Set up onBeforeAction hooks to login the user automatically (which asks for credentials if user is not logged in to external service)

```
var loginWithGoogle = function() {
  if (bla.isClient) {
    Session.set('loginError', undefined);
    bla.loginWithGoogle({
      loginStyle         : "redirect",
      requestPermissions : ['profile', 'email'],
      requestOfflineToken: true
    }, function (err) {
      if (err)
        Session.set('loginError', 'reason: ' + err.reason + ' message: ' + err.message || 'Unknown error');
    });
  }
}

var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! bla.user()) {
    if (bla.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate); 
    } else {
      console.log('Some crazy stuff');
      loginWithGoogle();
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['some-special-public-route']});
```

2) Log the user out when they are navigating away from every page (caveat: login/logout gets called everytime the user navigates within the app)

```
bla.startup(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        closingWindow();
    });
});

closingWindow = function(){
    console.log('You are leaving.');
    bla.logout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force to start a new session in case You need it using the **sessionControl**. Send a hit like :

```
ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, {‘sessionControl’: ‘start’});
```

Further info https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl

Answer (score 1):

There should be a request to `_utm.gif?` from the page. (See [this blog post](http://www.rachaelarnold.com/dev/archive/how-to-check-if-google-analytics-click-tracking-is-triggered) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12979232/1245190).)

Unfortunately I can't find out if/how it's possible to know if a request has been done from a page. [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8766745/1245190) is the best I quickly found.